# JS return result from list if *either* option A or option B is selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, filter

I created a filter for a list of scholarships and it was working fine using the code below, but now I realize that I need to be able to display a particular scholarship when **either** "Freshmen" or "Sophomores" is selected from the "Standing" dropdown—but I can't figure out how to include multiple standings per scholarship.

Is it possible to accomplish this with an adjustment to the code below, or have I set myself up for failure?

```
var filters = {
  need: "",
  standing: "",
};

need.value = filters.need;
standing.value = filters.standing;

need.addEventListener("input", function() {
  filters.need = need.value;
  update();
});

standing.addEventListener("input", function() {
  filters.standing = standing.value;
  update();
});


function filterNeed(scholarship) {
  return !filters.need.length || scholarship.need == filters.need;
}

function filterStanding(scholarship) {
  return !filters.standing.length || scholarship.standing == filters.standing;
}

function update() {
  let filteredCards = getScholarships().filter(filterNeed).filter(filterStanding);
  console.log(filters);
  output.innerHTML = filteredCards.map(scholarship => `<span><a href="${scholarship.link}">${scholarship.name}</a></span>`).join("");
};
update();


function getScholarships() {
  return [
  {
      name: "Scholarship 1",
      link: "#",
      need: "yes",
      standing: "Freshmen",
    },
    {
      name: "Scholarship 2",
      link: "#",
      need: "no",
      standing: "Sophomore",
    },
    {
      name: "Scholarship 3",
      link: "#",
      need: "yes",
      standing: "Junior",
    }
];
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rynq0mf3/

Comment: What's the issue with the current approach?

Comment: I can't, for example, have 2 "standings" for Scholarship 1—Freshmen and Sophomores. If I try to add multiple standings the output does not function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays:

```js
...
standing: ["Junior", "Sophomore"],
```

and fix `filterStanding`:

```js
function filterStanding(scholarship) {
  return !filters.standing.length || scholarship.standing.some(v => v == filters.standing);
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/flimflamsammy/a2v8q6hc/22/

Finally got it working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would someone be willing to show me how to filter within this form using some checkbox fields? I'd like to be able to filter by multiple underrepresented statuses (see fiddle).
https://jsfiddle.net/flimflamsammy/yhr4xb2z/2/